# Equivalent definition of the support of a measure on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on a topological space

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

Let $E$ be a topological space, $\mu$ be a measure on $\mathcal B(E)$ and $$\operatorname{supp}\mu:=\bigcap\left\{B\subseteq E:B\text{ is closed and }\mu(B^c)=0\right\}.$$ I want to show that $$\operatorname{supp}\mu=\left\{x\in E:\mu(N)>0\text{ for each open neighborhood }N\text{ of }x\right\}.\tag1$$

Unfortunately, I have no idea how we can prove this, but I guess we need impose some additional assumption (e.g. Hausdorfness). So, how can we show this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think they are equivalent for any space. Following lines are each equivalent (let $\mathcal B = \{B \subseteq E\colon B\text{ is closed and } \mu(B^c)=0\}$):

$$x \notin \bigcap_{B \in \mathcal B} B$$
$$\exists B \in \mathcal B: x\notin B$$
$$\exists N \subseteq E\colon x \in N, N\text{ is open and }\mu(N) = 0$$

So $x$ is not in $\operatorname{supp}$ with the first definition iff it is not in $\operatorname{supp}$ with the second definition.

Comment: We need $\forall N$ in the second definition.

Comment: We take inverse of statement. For $x \notin \operatorname{supp} \mu$ by second definition we need one open neighborhood of $x$ with zero measure.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I actually think it is correct as it is written. Could you elaborate on what's worrying you?